# Why using StandardScaler from sklearn before LogisticRegression increase avg cross_val_score? Standarization should only help in faster convergece

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using UC Irvine ML Glass Identification dataset mentioned in a book "Applied Predictive Modelling".

I tried rudimentary logistic regression models using sklearn with and without the StandardScaler class and had 2.3% improvement in accuracy when cv =5.

I did use pipeline to not leak the data but i am not sure if i leaked it somehow.

```
lr = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000, random_state=42)
results = cross_val_score(estimator=lr,cv=5,scoring="accuracy", X = glass_data.iloc[:,0:-1], y=glass_data.iloc[:,-1] )
# had to increase max iterations as data is unprocessed, gradient descent is too slow because of it.
np.mean(results)
```

above code had lower accuracy of **.579**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
 # since we did not divide our data set and are using cross validation, we need to use a pipeline 
# otherwise there will be data leakage 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

clf = Pipeline([("scaler", StandardScaler()), ("lr", LogisticRegression( random_state=42))])
result = cross_val_score(clf, cv=5, scoring="accuracy", X=glass_data.iloc[:,0:-1], y=glass_data.iloc[:,-1])
np.mean(result)
```

2nd code block had accuracy of **.6078**

Also, i did try to increase max_iter to a very large number for case 1 but the cross_val_score average was always the same.

I am just confused why there is increase in accuracy with feature scaling? Shouldn't it just help with faster convergence?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: For what it’s worth, the answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559152 reveals that this behavior is due to the surprising choice of defaults in `sklearn`, which is an implementation detail.